# Strengthening a clay rocket nozzle with sodium silicate and calcium chloride

Tags: bond

"I strengthen the bentonite clay nozzle by dipping the rammed nozzle in a $50\%$ 
 sodium silicate solution and allow to dry in warm oven. Then dip in a strong solution of Calcium Chloride, again dry. Then another dip in $50 - 70\%$ sodium silicate and again air dryed in warm oven. A third silicate treatment can be done. This makes for a strong nozzle that doesn't erode unless the motor thrust is over about $\pu{150kN}$." My question is: What is going on here chemically? Is it crosslinking?

Comment: The Na-silicate solution would seep into pores in the clay and polymerize into silica. Not sure why the dips in calcium chloride solution.

Comment: a google search shows that calcium chloride and sodium silicate react in water to make calcium silicate.  I am not exactly sure why that would strengthen/prevent erosion in a rocket nozzle, but further research shows that calcium silicate melts at 3,870 °F.  So I guess that's a clue.