# Can sodium silicate be made insoluble?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, solubility

In [this question](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/102027/strengthening-a-clay-rocket-nozzle-with-sodium-silicate-and-calcium-chloride), the user asked about curing sodium silicate with calcium chloride. My question is, will the resultant product be insoluble in water? I know calcium silicate is only very slightly soluble, but I'm expecting it's going to be a bit more complicated than that.
I'm not a chemist, and wanted to know the answer to something I'm messing with at work to know if I need to hire a materials professional.

Comment: No, it is really as simple as that. You'll get calcium silicate, which is insoluble.

Comment: Where does the sodium go, in this case? Is it displaced into the water to become sodium chloride? And would the calcium propagate through a "thick" structure, or would this only be a surface coating?

Comment: Yes, Na remains as NaCl. And yes, propagation may be an issue.

Comment: That's alright, I only need a surface coating. If water can get to it, CaCl2 can get to it during the wash and then it's 'sealed'.

Comment: It really doesn't matter whether this is actual homework or not. I have decided to reopen the question, because I don't think it should have been closed as homework in the first place.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, Ivan's comment answers my question perfectly, but as it's a comment rather than an answer, I can't mark it as such.